# How safe is it to directly modify message member vectors in c++?

Tags: ros, c++, messages, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a custom message class A that contains vectors (of other message classes, but I think that's immaterial).

Is it safe to mess around with the vectors directly, by resizing them, inserting things into them, etc?

My concern is that A's header might contain some metadata about A's vector, which becomes out-of-date when I modify A's vector.

-- Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46699/how-safe-is-it-to-directly-modify-message-member-vectors-in-c++?/) by [SuperElectric](https://answers.ros.org/users/3461/superelectric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is nothing like a message header that contains hidden meta-information in ROS. Modifying message members is save and is even necessary to fill messages before publishing them.

But do not const-cast and modify messages you received in message callbacks.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3